# Calling a function in a currently displayed fragment from Application

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I hav a fragment in my MainActivity which displays a loading pic as of now, while I call a function in my XMLReader Application class from the MainActivity itself. The XMLReader uses an asynctask to read an xml file from an online server. after execution, i need to alert the fragment that currently shows the loading pic to refresh to something else. My question is how do i alert the currently displayed fragment? or atleast alert the Activity so that i can call a different fragment.

read somewhere that putting a broadcast listener would be overkill, is it my only way?

Comment: Do you display your fragments in a viewpager or what?

Comment: I display them in a viewpager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the current visible item in viewpager:

```
// from activity
int position = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
Fragment currentItem = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
```

If you want to callback the activity from fragment:

```
// call custom method update() in activity from fragment
((MainActivity) getActivity()).update();
```

Comment: So anyway to alert the activity from application class? or should i move the implementation to another fragment without UI?

Comment: I think call the alert to activity will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the current visible item in viewpager:

```
// from activity
int position = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
YourFragment yourFragment = (YourFragment) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
yourFragment.refreshSomething();
```